# Specify different conditions for different columns in the same Query

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I specify different conditions for different columns in the same Query?
 

According to my understanding, conditions are specified in where clause that are applied to whole table. But if I want a single condition to single column and there are multiple columns which has different conditions with the same field, how can I specify conditions.

My case, 
I have a table A with 10 column for instance. 
I have to filter each column with condition between certain dates. ie, 
sum of column A1 between date 01/01/1990 and 01/10/1990 
sum of column A2 between date 01/01/1992 and 01/10/1992 
and similarly other columns. 
All these i have to proceed  in single query.  
This date is also available in A table 
Can I use sum(A1) over(partition by date between to_date('01/01/1990') and to_date('01/10/1990')) ? 
If yeah, I am unable to use between in partition by. I get error "missing right parenthesis". 
 
Please explain. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please share your table's structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm not supposed to share table. Can you please consider the above description about the table and its columns. Date is in date format. Other columns in number fomat.

Comment: Just call the table tableA, and the columns c1, c2 etc. And make up some sample data...

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want to return results where column A1 is in one date range, OR column A2 is between another, or when both conditions are true? If you can't share the table's data, please share its structure (with field names obfuscated if necessary) and sample data.

Comment: Or do a search on SQL joins, which allow you to join a number of queries together like you probably want.

Comment: A1 on Condition c1 to be true,A2 on Condition c2 to be true, An on condition cn to be true. Each column holds a condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:-

```
select 
a.col1,
sum (case when a.YourDateColumn between to_date ('01/01/1900', 'DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date ('01/10/1990', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then a.a1 else 0 end) as a1total,
sum (case when a.YourDateColumn between to_date ('01/01/1992', 'DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date ('01/10/1992', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then a.a2 else 0 end) as a2total
from A 
group by a.col1
```